# Need to call query in set hours from table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to call a query in set hours. A table will contain the query, start hour & end hour using which I need to call the query mentioned in table.

What I have tried.

```
select query 
from tblQuery 
where datepart(hour, getdate()) between starthour and endhour
```

In table

```
Starthour = 13
Endhour = 14
```

This is working fine for same day. But in case I need it for Starthour = 13
and Endhour = 2 (i.e today 13:00 to tomorrow 2:00) how can this be achieved.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Providing the table schema also helps...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic like this:

```
where (starthour <= endhour and datepart(hour, getdate()) between starthour and endhour) or
      (starthour > endhour and datepart(hour, getdate()) not between starthour and endhour)
```

Note:  The second part does not include the `starthour` and `endhour`.  It is not clear if that is desired or not.  If so, then use explicit comparisons:

```
where (starthour <= endhour and
       datepart(hour, getdate()) >= starthour and
       datepart(hour, getdate()) <= endhour
      ) or
      (starthour > endhour and
       (datepart(hour, getdate()) <= starthour and
        datepart(hour, getdate()) >= endhour
       )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Use date comparison instead of isolating the hour section.</s>

Something like:  `... WHERE getDate() >= startDate AND getDate() <= endDate`

Since `startDate` and `endDate` should store the date and time.

Maybe use `SET dateNow = getDate();` to reduce method calls.

edit: the problem your facing is `BETWEEN` will not behave as intended if the first argument is larger. so you can't wrap 24->0 easily.

edit2: heres a better solution that doesn't require updating:

```
SET hourNow = datepart(hour, getdate());
SELECT query 
FROM tblQuery
WHERE (endHour >= startHour AND hourNow BETWEEN startHour AND endHour) 
OR (endHour < startHour AND hourNow NOT BETWEEN endHour + 1 AND startHour - 1);
```

(I have to admit it is difficult to tell your context, is the table a list of scheduled tasks?)

edit3: added increments to the negative comparison because BETWEEN is fully inclusive. But it doesn't work for always on tasks...(unless set 0-23)

It may be more appropriate to use:

```
SET hourNow = datepart(hour, getdate());
SELECT query 
FROM tblQuery
WHERE (endHour > startHour AND hourNow BETWEEN startHour AND endHour - 1) 
OR (endHour < startHour AND hourNow NOT BETWEEN endHour AND startHour - 1)
OR (endHour = startHour);
```

This excludes the end hour and includes the start hour. Therefore you will need to add 1 to every endHour for the same functionality (this only needs to be done once).